# "Not enough memory for stack (1040 bytes needed, 920 bytes available)"

Tags: pic, memory

I'm uploading my recent code into a [PIC32MX575F512H-80I/PT](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/PIC32MX575F512H-80I%2FPT/PIC32MX575F512H-80I%2FPT-ND/2184458) and I'm getting this message:

```
Error: Not enough memory for stack (1040 bytes needed, 920 bytes available)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And I found this info on the message box:

```
Dynamic Data-Memory Reservation
heap  41000  Reserved for heap 
stack   904  Reserved for stack
```

I'm using the MPLAB X 2.26 and I want to know how can I increase the stack memory? 
How can I do the calculations properly? Should I remove memory from heap memory and apply it to the stack memory?

Comment: I don't even have MPLAB, but I have google. Why can't you do this? https://microchip.wikidot.com/mplabx:creating-a-heap

Comment: My real problem is related how do I make the calculations to increase it properly. 
In my Project properties inside the Pickit tab I have the field "Program memory Start " and " Program memory end" and in the text box below I have "start >= 0x1d000000 and start = 0x1d07ffff If start is not equal to 0x1d000000, then start = 0x200*n "

Comment: Then try to ask the *right* question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some big arrays but the problem for my case was the allocated heap memory. It was too much and unnecessary so I removed some memory from the heap and decreased from 41k to 35k. Now is working perfectly. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using the XC32 compiler.
Right-click your project, select 'properties' (or click file->project properties)
Find and click on xc32-ld under XC32(Global Options)
Type in a number next to Minimum stack size (bytes). Choose a number larger than however many it says it needs in your error message ...
[image]

Comment: Thanks @brhans. you helped me but my inner question is how do I calculate the stack size properly?

Comment: Its voodoo ... You need to know an awful lot about how your compiler uses the stack, how many levels of function nesting you have, etc, etc, etc ...

Comment: I already increased the minimum stack size for 1300 and now I'm getting this:

Error: Not enough memory for stack (1316 bytes needed, 920 bytes available)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status


Remember for the last iteration I increased the minimum stack size from "empty field" to 1300.
Did I reached the maximum size for the stack memory?

Comment: I suspect you're running low on RAM in your PIC and 920 is all that's left after all of your variables have been allocated. Do you have some large arrays ?